# change font depending on how many caracters are typed

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the font size using JavaScript on an input field depending on how many characters are typed. For instance, the default font size is 16px, but if I add more than 10 characters, the font size to become 12px.

HTML:

```
<div class="phone-input">
    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="tocall" value="">
```

and css:

```
input#tocall {
    width: 145px;
    padding: 6px 3px;
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

I am unfamiliar working with JavaScript so please help me.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel i have only html: <div class="phone-input"><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="tocall" value="">
and css: input#tocall {
        width: 145px;
padding: 6px 3px;
color: #424242;
font-size: 16px;
border: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;}

no idea how to make the js

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting markup in comments.

Comment: Why is your input having read only property set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like in the snippet below, if you just leave `readonly` out of your `input`, now you can't type anything into it.

```
var input = document.getElementById('tocall');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.target.value.length > 10) {
        e.target.style.fontSize = '12px';
    } else {
        e.target.style.fontSize = '16px';
    }
    return;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this...

In JavaScript, access the text as

```
myInput = document.getElementById('tocall');
myText = myInput.value;
```

Then find the size of text as

```
len = myText.length
```

Now, check this value and use CSS to change font size.

```
if (len > 10) {
    myInput.style.fontSize = "10px";
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add an event handler to keep track of the current value in `myInput`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel The input field in read only, so no point in adding a handler.